# how receive information and data other app for my flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, share

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Image Content</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.image</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

i use this code and

```
 mport 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:receive_sharing_intent/receive_sharing_intent.dart';
```

this plugins but i can't find my app in gallery
for share recommend app
[image]

[image]

I really want to see my flutter app in the list of recommended sharing apps
Also in the Show More list
My app doesn't appear